# GWT Editor use IsEditor<LeafValueEditor<Date>> to populate Long field

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-editors

I just got the hang of using the `Editor framework` and am porting over all my forms to use it.  I'm running into some trouble on my `Event` form.  I have 5 different `time fields` - for each field I use a `DateBox` to allow the user to select the time.

In my old `Activity` i converted the values of these fields to `Long` times, populated my `proxy object` and persisted it.

I want to do the same thing using the `Editor framework`.  Is there anyway I can use an `Editor` with a `DateBox` to populate a `Long` field in my domain object.  I'm sure there's got to be a way to do this I'm just having trouble figuring it out.

If this is not the case and I just can't do this for now, does anybody know a good solution for how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to wrap the `DateBox` in an `Editor<Long>`. Something like:

```
@Editor.Ignore
@UiField
DateBox dateField;

LeafValueEditor<Long> longField = new LeafValueEditor<Long>() {
    @Override
    public Long getValue() {
        Date date = dateField.getValue();
        return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
    }
    @Override
    public void setValue(Long value) {
        Date date = value == null ? null : new Date(value.longValue());
        dateField.setValue(date);
    }
}
```